# How to write to a tempfile then execute it as a subprocess in Python?

Tags: python, subprocess, execute

I want to write to a file, then execute it as a subprocess. However, writing to the file normally then executing it results in the subprocess.run() call failing with `OSError: [Errno 26] Text file busy: /tmp/<filename>`. I'm running this on Linux. A minimal example is (imports+shebang removed for readability, otherwise this is the whole file):

```py
def chmod_plus_x(file_path: str) -> None:
    st = os.stat(file_path)
    os.chmod(file_path, st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)

try:
    script = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    f = open(script.name, "w")
    f.write("ls /")
    f.flush()
    f.close()
    chmod_plus_x(script.name)

    subprocess.run(script.name, shell=False)
finally:
    os.remove(script.name)
```

I am aware `with open(...)` is better code, but it results in the same error, and for the sake of the question I'm trying to be explicit about the file being closed. As I understand it, this error is raised when an executable attempts to be simultaneously executed and open for writing, but the file is definitely not open at the time of execution. Or at least, it shouldn't be. Why is the file still open?

Comment: Does adding a shebang (e.g. `#!/bin/bash`) to the generated script help?

Comment: I tried your code as is and got `OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: <path>`. However with `shell=True` then it works. As for the text file busy, I guess you are on Windows. I run it from my Mac.

Comment: @HaiVu I'm on Linux, I've updated my post to mention it. shell=True does not fix the issue: an exception is no longer raised, but the script still fails to execute due to "Text file busy".

Comment: Post the full stack trace.  I'd expect similar error to be raised when you try removing file, while suprocess is still running/being launched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NamedTemporaryFile` returns a file like object, which contains a handle to the opened file. So the error message is correct: the file is still open.

You should directly write to `script` and above all close it before trying to run it:

```
...
try:
    script = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
    script.write("ls /")
    script.flush()
    script.close()
    chmod_plus_x(script.name)

    subprocess.run(script.name, shell=False)
finally:
    os.remove(script.name)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative to your solution:

```py
import os
import subprocess
import tempfile


def main():
    try:
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False) as script:
            script.write("ls /\n")
        subprocess.run(["/bin/sh", script.name])
    finally:
        os.remove(script.name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### Notes

- I created a temp file object and call it `script`
- By default, this file opens with a `mode="w+b", but I specifically want mode "w" to enable writing of text, not bytes.
- After exiting the `with` block, the file is closed, which should avoid the "text file busy" error
- Instead of chmod, I run `/bin/sh script.name`, which should work the same way. You can use your own shell here, such as /bin/bash, /usr/bin/zsh, ...

#### Update

Instead of using the try/finally construct, I can use the `atexit` library to provide clean up. This makes the code a little simpler and less deeply nested.

```py
import atexit
import os
import subprocess
import tempfile


def main():
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False) as script:
        script.write("ls /\n")
        atexit.register(os.unlink, script.name)
    subprocess.run(["/bin/sh", script.name])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In case of an exeption, the `atexit` handler I registered still got executed.

#### Update 2

I looked into not using '/bin/sh' and here is what I came up with:

```py
import atexit
import os
import stat
import subprocess
import tempfile


def chmod_plus_x(file_path: str) -> None:
    st = os.stat(file_path)
    os.chmod(file_path, st.st_mode | stat.S_IEXEC)


def main():
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="w", delete=False) as script:
        script.write("ls /\n")
    atexit.register(os.unlink, script.name)
    chmod_plus_x(script.name)
    subprocess.run([script.name], shell=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

#### Notes 2

- Again, the file should be closed after the `with` statement, so we should not see the "busy" error
- Even without specifying "/bin/sh", it is likely be /bin/sh or /bin/bash is used to execute your script.

Comment: This works, but it's because the executable is /bin/sh rather than the script itself. Because the script isn't being executed, there's no conflict between writing to the file and executing it. I've updated the post to rephrase the emphasis of the question, in particular I'm curious to know why it is that the file is still considered "open"? (my reasoning behind this is I need to capture stdout and stderr of the script separately, which I can't do when the process is bash rather than the script itself)

Comment: Apologies, I think that last bit of my previous comment may be inaccurate and there was a bug in my code, but it's too late to edit it. Still curious about the answer though.

Comment: Please see my update 2. Let me know if it works for you.